# Is there an equivalent to "format painter" (Microsoft formatting tool) in Ableton when editing MIDI notes?

Tags: midi, daw, ableton-live, production

For example, I recently had a two MIDI chords.  They were the same chord, but one was eighth notes and the other was quarter notes.  Is there a quick way to apply the "formatting" (read: rhythm) of the first chord to that of the second chord?

[image: an example where I'd like to quickly make the second midi chord comprised of 16th(?) notes, without having to re-draw every note.]

Comment: Do you want the same number of notes for the second chord before and after (e.g. start with 2 quarter note chords, end with 2 8th note-8th rest chords), or do you want the second chords taking up the same time before and after (e.g. start with 2 quarter note chords, end with 4 8th note chords)?

Comment: @Dekkadeci not totally following your question, but the image I added above should help.  Thanks!

Comment: Those don't really look like 8th notes at all to me. The closest to 8th notes I can detect is the pattern in the G3s. I cannot tell if the pattern in the A3s is continuous or incredibly choppy (I've never worked with Ableton).

Comment: @Dekkadeci that's besides the point